# How to get node.js console.error and console.warn output in color

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to get node.js to output console.error and console.warn messages in color?

I'm hoping I can make all console.error messages red, console.warn messages yellow, and console.log messages the default color.

I looked around for a command line argument or environment variable option for node.exe, but I don't see anything.  Perhaps colored console messages are something I have to opt into a different way?

I'd like a solution for Windows 10, in case that matters.

Comment: You're looking for a logging or ANSI colors library.

Comment: There's perhaps a subtle but specific difference: I'm looking to colorize the output of console.error.

Comment: You can reassign the `console` functions.

Comment: Interesting, @SLaks. It never occurred to me to do that.  If you wrote that as an answer with example code, I would mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the colors package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors

Just use a wrapper for how you want them formatted

```
module.exports = {
  error: message => console.log(message.red),
  warn: message => console.log(message.yellow),
}
```

You could also use a logging library like pino that will colorize the log level in the message.

https://github.com/pinojs/pino

EDIT: To show basic logger file implementation

my-custom-logger.js

```
module.exports = {
  error: message => console.log(message.red),
  warn: message => console.log(message.yellow),
  info: message => console.log(message.green),
  debug: message => console.log(message.blue),
};
```

some-file.js

```
const logger = require('./my-custom-logger);

logger.error('Something went very wrong');
logger.warn('I am just a warning');
logger.info('This is informational');
logger.debug('Let us dig a little deeper');
```

What's nice about hiding it behind your own `my-custom-logger.js` file is that you can swap out the implementation behind the scenes without changing all of your code.

I would highly suggest looking deeper into pino, bunyan or winston as a logging framework.  There are many benefits but the 2 biggest ones in my opinion are:

1. The ability to raise/lower your log level to control how verbose your logging is
2. Print out objects in JSON format and not using `JSON.stringify(object)`

Comment: Yeah, I know about the _colors_ package.  But I don't know how to hook _colors_ up to console.error vs console.warn vs console.log.

Comment: Why don't you hide it behind a `logging.js` file?

Comment: I don't know what is entailed.  What I'm hearing is that I can require some custom _mylog_ function and then mylog.error or mylog.warn my way to colored output.  I guess that's good enough.  I'm just not sure how to make that intercept the existing console.* calls. Or if that's even possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the methods in `console` to wrapper functions that call the underlying methods (which you will need to store) but wrap them in colors.

Beware that you can also pass objects to `console` methods, which would be trickier to handle.

```
const actualError = console.error;

console.error = function(...args) {
  actualError(...args.map(a => typeof a === 'string' ? colorize(a) : a);
};
```